# Rule for squaring arbitrary powers?

Tags: linear-algebra

This is a really simple question, but I don't know how to phrase it well enough for Google. I'm going through a proof and don't understand how:

$$
(q^{2^{n+1}})^2 = q^{2^{n+2}}
$$

I thought it would be $q^{4^{n+1}}$instead, or are they equivalent? If so, why?

Comment: if you don't want to make that mistake again, remember that $(q^{2^{n+1}})^2 = (q^{2^{n+1}})(q^{2^{n+1}}) = q^{2^{n+1} + 2^{n+1}}$

Answer (score 11, accepted):

They are not equivalent because $2^{n+2}\not= 2^{2n+2}=2^{2(n+1)}=(2^2)^{n+1}=4^{n+1}$.

Use the followings carefully :

$$(q^a)^b=q^{a\color{red}{\times} b}$$
and
$$2^c\times 2^d=2^{c\color{red}{+}d}.$$

---

$$\big (q^{2^{n+1}})^2=q^{2^{n+1}\times 2}=q^{2^{n+1}\times 2^1}=q^{2^{n+1+1}}=q^{2^{n+2}}$$

Answer (score 4):

They are not equivalent.

Nested powers work like this:

$$(a^b)^c = a^{bc}$$

Note that this is different from

$$a^{(b^c)} = a^{b^c}$$

---

In your example,

\begin{align*}
\left(q^{2^{n+1}}\right)^2 &= q^{2 \cdot 2^{n+1}}\\
&=q^{2^{n+2}}
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, we can look at an example.

Let $q=3$, and $n=1$. Then $$q^{2^{n+1}} = 3^{2^{2}} = 3^4 = 81.$$

If we square this we get $$\left(q^{2^{n+1}}\right)^2 = (3^{4})^2 = 81^2= 6561.$$

However, notice that $$q^{4^{n+1}} = 3^{4^2} = 3^{16} = 43046721.$$

This is a bit larger than $6561$, so the two expressions are not equal.